# How to login to microsoft account for web request

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory

I am attempting to get data from `https://[org uri].crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/aadusers`.

Docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/sr-cyrl-rs/power-apps/developer/data-platform/aaduser-entity

If I am logged in to my Microsoft account and go to the URL, I get back the correct data from the API. If I am not logged in, I get a http 401 response which makes sense.

I am working on a .NET app and want the app to be able to get and parse the resulting data.

How can my app 'login' to Microsoft to make the `GET` request?

I tried adding a basic auth header to the request, no luck.

I then tried:

```
var credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
var handler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = credentials };

using (var http = new HttpClient(handler))
{
    http.GetAsync("https://[org uri].crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/aadusers");
}
```

which also returned a http 401.

Comment: Do you want to make use of app to autheticate to dynamics crm?

Comment: @Rukmini thanks for your question. Not really, i want the app to login to my microsoft account, once it has done that it will have access to the above listed url.

Comment: AFAIK Dynamics CRM API is used in a business or enterprise context, where must have work or school accounts that are associated with an Azure AD tenant and so Dynamics CRM allows access to work or school accounts to prevent unauthorized access and protect sensitive data.

Comment: And ROPC flow that is ("username", "password") flow is not supported for ROPC

Answer (score 0):

After more googling, Ii found exactly what I was looking for.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/dotnet-app-only